# Why there is a error on g++ when using operator class_name() & c style cast

Tags: c++

Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ：

required headers in The OpenCL C++ Wrapper API 1.2 (revision 09)

```
#include <cl/cl.hpp>
class TBuffer
{
public:
    // some code
    operator cl::Buffer& ();

    operator cl_mem ();
    // some code
private:
    // some code
    cl::Buffer m_Buffer;
    // some codes
};

TBuffer::operator cl::Buffer& ()
{
    return m_Buffer;
}
TBuffer::operator cl_mem ()
{
    return (cl_mem) m_Buffer();
}

class TMatrix : public TBuffer
{

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    TMatrix mat;
    cl::Kernel kernel;
    kernel.setArg(0,(cl::Buffer)mat);
    return 0;
}
```

the code work well on visual studio 2012, but get error on g++ 4.9.2:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cpp:35:30: error: call of overloaded 'Buffer(TMatrix&)' is ambiguous
  kernel.setArg(0,(cl::Buffer)mat);
```

Comment: Does `Buffer` have a constructor taking `TMatrix` or `TBuffer`?

Comment: You need to show the prototype for `kernel.setArg`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, add & behind cl::Buffer, like this:

```
m_kernel.setArg(10, (cl::Buffer&)_img_src);
```

But I still don't know why it work well on visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the information you provided in your answer, I think I know what the problem is.

`m_kernel`'s `setArg` most probably takes its argument by reference (i.e a `cl::Buffer&`).

A cast to a value type copy-constructs a temporary of that type. However, a temporary can't bind to a non-const reference, so you can't pass it to `setArg`.

Moreover, `setArgs` probably has two more overloads, both of which could be called by an implicit conversion of that temporary to their parameter's type. But as both functions are equally valid, overload resolution fails with an "ambiguous call" error.

Casting to a reference type yields a reference, and so the first overload is an exact match, no problem here.

The reason it works with MSVC is that it enables by default an extension that *does* allow non-`const` references to bind to temporaries. Thus the first overload, which wasn't compatible before, is now selected as an exact match, before the others.

Comment: thanks for you answer.
Kernel is in The OpenCL C++ Wrapper API 1.2 (revision 09).   defined as
class Kernel
{
...
    template <typename T>
    cl_int setArg(cl_uint index, T value)
    {
        ...
    }
}

Comment: I have create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Please have a look, thank you.